# select not indicating arrival of data in function launched by pthread_create

Tags: c, select, pthreads

I've written a simple multi-threaded TCP echo server for experimenting with threads. Below is the code for my main function.

```
#include "server_lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Server s = setup_socket();
  pthread_t clients[MAX_CLIENT];

  int connfd, rv = 0;

  client_data.client_number = 0;
  for(;;) {
    connfd = accept(s.sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&s.sa, (socklen_t*)&s.addrlen);

    if (connfd < 0 && errno != EAGAIN)
      handle_error("accept failed");

    if (connfd > 0) {
      client_data.client_number++;
      if (client_data.client_number <= MAX_CLIENT) {
        socket_nonblocking(&connfd);
        disable_nagles_algo(&connfd);

        /* Send the client number to client first */
        rv = send(connfd, (void *)&client_data.client_number,
                  sizeof(client_data.client_number), 0);
        ThreadDataT *t = (ThreadDataT*)malloc(sizeof(ThreadDataT));
        t->fd = connfd;

        if (pthread_create(&clients[client_data.client_number-1], NULL, HandleMessage, (void*)t) != 0){
          handle_error("pthread_create failed");
        }
        /* Lets close our copy of connfd */
      }
        else {
          rv = send(connfd, "Max clients reached!\n", 21, 0);
          client_data.client_number--;
          close(connfd);
        }
    }

    usleep(100000);
  }

  close(s.sockfd);
}
```

Here is the code for HandleMessage function which is called via pthread_create.

```
void* HandleMessage(void *data) {
  /* Lets detach first */
  pthread_detach(pthread_self());

  struct timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = 0;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;

  ThreadDataT *t = (ThreadDataT*)data;
  fd_set testfd;

  FD_ZERO(&testfd); FD_SET(t->fd, &testfd);

  int rv = 0;

  for (;;) {
    int result = select(FD_SETSIZE, &testfd, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (result < 0) {
      perror("select failed");
      pthread_exit(&result);
    }


    if (result > 0) {
      if(FD_ISSET(t->fd, &testfd)) {
        /* We have some data */
        rv = echo_content(&t->fd);
        if (rv < 0) {
          if (rv != -10)
            perror("echo_content failed");
          close(t->fd);
          free(t);
          pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
      }
    }

    usleep(1000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Below is code for echo_content function as requested in comment.

```
int echo_content(int *connfd) {
  unsigned char buffer[2048];
  int size = recv(*connfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
  if (size < 0)
    handle_error("recv");

  if (size > 0) {
    if (strstr((const char*)buffer, "quit") != NULL){
      printf("Closing connection with client\n");
      send(*connfd, "bye\n", 4, 0);
      return -10;
    }

    size = send(*connfd, buffer, size, 0);
  } else
    printf("WARNING: Failed to recieve data\n");

  return size;
}
```

Data structures used by code are defined as follows.

```
#ifndef __SERVER_LIB_H__
#define __SERVER_LIB_H__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
  do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while(0)

#define PORT 50000
#define MAX_CLIENT 2

typedef struct {
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in sa;
  int addrlen;
} Server;

typedef unsigned char ClientNumber;

typedef struct {
  ClientNumber clients[MAX_CLIENT];
  short client_number;
} ClientDataT;

ClientDataT client_data;;

typedef struct {
  int fd;
} ThreadDataT;

Server setup_socket(void);
int echo_content(int *);
void socket_nonblocking(int *);
void disable_nagles_algo(int *);
void* HandleMessage(void*);

#endif /* __SERVER_LIB_H__ */
```

After compiling above code and I can connect to it using telnet. I did not see the client number sent by server in telnet. Next I entered some message and was expecting it to echoed back but that did not happen.

While debugging I noticed that select system call in HandleMEssage always returns 0 no matter what I enter at client side. Just to test I then set writefds argument of select and then select returns value > 0 and indicates socket is expecting to be written. The same code was working with fork model. (The fork based code is [here](https://github.com/copyninja/tls-echo-server/blob/master/src/server.c)).

Code is almost similar to fork based one, so I'm bit lost on why it is not working. Can any one point me on what I might be doing wrong here?.

Comment: Well, 'socket_nonblocking(&connfd);' why, when you are threading off the client<>server socket handling?

Comment: What does 'rv = echo_content(&t->fd);' do, and what's with all the select() gunge in a one-thread-per-client server?

Comment: Hi Martin, non_blocking code was from the original legacy code base. Yes I can drop it. Also I've added definition of echo_content function. Code can work without select I know but I'm just curious why select is not indicating arrival of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be other problems too, but try to move the FD_SET() inside the loop:

```
  for (;;) {
    FD_SET(t->fd, &testfd);
    int result = select(FD_SETSIZE, &testfd, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
```

AFIK, select() call modify fd-sets, and may remove testfd from the set.

Another possible problem is the zero timeout of your select() call. man page of select says:

> If both fields of the
>          timeval structure are zero, then select() returns immediately.  (This
>          is useful for polling.)  If timeout is NULL (no timeout), select()
>          can block indefinitely.

You could also try the indefinitely timeout:

```
  for (;;) {
    FD_SET(t->fd, &testfd);
    int result = select(FD_SETSIZE, &testfd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

That way you can remove the ugly polling sleep: `usleep(1000);`.

Comment: Thank you that FD_SET was the key :-). Also yes it indeed does not make sense to use 0 timeout and then sleep. I've updated code to make select indefinitely block and dropped the sleep.